# About different definitions of projective tangent space.

Tags: algebraic-geometry

I believe Harris defined $\mathbb{T}_pX:=\{[Z_0:\dots Z_n]|\frac{\partial F}{\partial Z_i}Z_i=0\}$ and then he (re)defined an equivalent notion of $\mathbb{T}_pX:=\{[v\wedge \frac{\partial v}{\partial z_1}\wedge \dots \wedge \frac{\partial v}{\partial z_n}]\}$, but this looks like essentially different, in particular, the first definition seems to yield a hyperplane, but the second definition yields a point. How are they equivalent?